# How should I structure my classes and files in python?

Tags: python, coding-style

My code is currently in one big file:

```
# file 1: ./mainfile.py
class Namespace:
    class This:
        ...
    class That:
        ...

mainFunc(Namespace.This(), Namespace.That())
```

I would like my code to look something like this:

```
# file 1: ./namespace/this.py
class This:
    ...

# file 2: ./namespace/that.py
class That:
    ...

# file 3: ./mainfile.py
import ???
mainFunc(Namespace.This(), Namespace.That())
```

What changes do I have to make so that I can still use exactly the same call to `mainFunc()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a package.  See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Comment: I got to this part. I put the class `This` in the file `namespace/this.py`, but when I `import namespace.this` in the main file, I get an error saying `ImportError: No module named namespace`

Comment: @f.ardelian: did you add the `__init__.py` file into the directory `namespace`?

Comment: Okay, that solved one thing. Now, do you know anything about using `Namespace.This()` instead of `Namespace.this.This()`?

Comment: I believe in Python, if you want them to be in the same namespace, the proper way to do it is to put all of the code in a `namespace.py` module file.  I know that coming from other languages you might have a desire to have separate files, but that's not Python.  (You can however accomplish this with some hacking in the `__init__.py` file, but I don't recommend it.)